# matlab: how to fill one side of the plot with one color, the remainder with another

Tags: matlab

Inspired by the old age of empires (picture from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aoe2/comments/4quogg/how_do_you_read_this_timeline/)), I would like to create a plot with that splits the pane into two colors at the plotted line. How can this be achieved?

Code:

```
separator=randi(100,1,20);
figure; hold on; plot(separator);
%below the separator it should be blue, above red
```

[image]

Comment: You probably want `area`, but a [mcve] here would be invaluable. "Please reproduce this screenshot" is pretty broad, give us some usable numbers.

Comment: I think in this case the example was basically the answer, so I just posted it :-/. I agree the screenshot may be more nostalgia than useful.

Comment: that's why it's so important to create a [mcve]! Often you find the answer yourself, always you make it easier for someone else to find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @Wolfie who helped me figure it out

```
y_max = 100;
separator=randi(y_max,1,20);
figure; hold on; area([separator;y_max-separator]');
```

[image]